# how to move an element from current index to another index (grid)

Tags: php, html

I'm currently working on a RPG Game using php.

```
$map = array(
    array(0,0,1,1,1,0),
    array(1,1,1,0,1,1),
    array(1,0,0,0,0,0),
    array(1,1,1,0,0,0),
    array(1,0,0,0,0,0),
    array(2,0,0,0,0,0)
);
```

The above code is my 2d array.

```
 for($i=0;$i<6;$i++){
                    echo "<tr>";
                    for($l = 0; $l<6; $l++){

                        if($map[$i][$l]==0) {
                            echo "<th class='wall'>".$i."</th>";

                        }
                        else if($map[$i][$l]==1){
                            echo "<th class='grass'>".$l."</th>";
                        }



                        if($map[$i][$l]==2){
                            $_SESSION['pos_I'] = $i;
                            $_SESSION['pos_L'] = $l;

                        $charPos = "<th class='grass'><img src='char/guy1/".$_SESSION['playerPos']."'></th>";
                        echo $charPos;

                        $_SESSION['charPos'] = $charPos;
                        }

                    }
                    echo "</tr>";

                }
```

During navigation, I want to move the image on that specific location basing from my grid. How do I do that?

Comment: save element in variable and remove it, then paste variable to place you want to element be

Comment: i have this x and y coordinate which sets the character position, then im thinking of using the coordinates to compare with the loops i have above, how do I compare these two or perhaps how do I access the exact location? @FilipKováč

Comment: character position is where is 2 value in 2d array ? then this is you condition `if($map[$i][$l]==2)`

Comment: yes, exactly i have that condition already. if i navigate it to go up, then it should be on $map[4][0] right? how do i access that and insert the image there? @FilipKováč

Comment: just set `$map[$i][$l]` to 0/1 wall/grass and if he move upward I do not know your coordinates, so for example set `$map[$i+1][$l] = 2` you can change +1 for -1 if go back or $l+1/-1 left/right